# How to change the initial content of DraftJS Editor as the state change?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I initiated an Editor with some content using Draft.js. The initial content defined in the state as given in the example below. How can I replace the entire content with new content when I change the state. From the following example I tried the `state` `initData` is given as `What is your name?` when the user clicks on the `input button` the state changes to `Quel est votre nom?` and the transelated content should replace the editor.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertFromHTML} from 'draft-js';

export default class DraftEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      initData: "What is your name?"           //Initial data and will be updated on button click
    };
    this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);

    const blocksFromHtml = this.state.initData;
    const html = blocksFromHtml;
    const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(html)
    const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
      blocksFromHTML.entityMap
    );
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
      this.setState({editorState});
    }
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  };

  changeContent() {
    this.setState({ initData: "Quel est votre nom?" });   //This is the data that will be replaced the initial data
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <input type='button' value="change" onClick={this.changeContent} />
            <Editor editorState={editorState} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentState to initialize the editor and to change the initial content as well.
To initialize, instead of `EditorState.createEmpty()` plus all the other lines of code in your constructor, use:

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
               ContentState.createFromText('What is your name?')
              ),
};
```

To change this data in your click handler, do something like the following:

```
      changeContent() {
        this.setState({
             editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
                          ContentState.createFromText('Quel est votre nom?')
                          )
         });   
       }
```